# How do I avoid errors copying to the Clipboard using navigator.clipboard.writeText using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a Javascript Password Generator as an assignment. I decided to add to the assignment a function at the end that would take the generated password and copy it to the clipboard.  I originally started to use:

```
document.execCommand("copy")
```

and then while researching found it was considered obsolete by MDN.
I then found:

```
navigator.clipboard.writeText(password.value)
```

and have tried to use that.

When running the code in real-time I receive the error: ***An error occurred copying the text to the clipboard.***

But when I use Breakpoints in DevTools and stop the script on lines 103 and 104, then continue after a second or so, the copy works.

So I am hoping someone can explain the reason and if I have to write a delay interval into the code.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Kevin O's Password Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../passGen/assets/css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../passGen/assets/css/ko_passGen_style.css" />
    
</head>

<body>
    <div class="px-1 pt-0 pt-sm-4 wrapper">

        <main class="my-0 my-sm-1 card">
            <header class = "px-2 text-white bg-dark card-header">
                <h1>Kev1n O's Pa$$word Gener@tor</h1>
            </header>

            <!-- Sub Head -->
            <div class="card-header text-center">
                <h2>Generate a Password</h2>
            </div>

            <!-- Password returned in this area -->
            <div class="card-body">
                <textarea readonly id="password" placeholder="Your Secure Password"
                    aria-label="Generated Password"></textarea>
            </div>

            <section class = "card-body">

                <h5>After you click the button below you will be asked the following 5 questions regarding your
                    password.</h5>

                <ol>
                    <li><b>How many characters</b> would you like your password to be?</li>
                    <li>Would you like <b>Numbers</b> ?</li>
                    <li>Would you like <b>Uppercase Letters</b> ?</li>
                    <li>Would you like <b>Lowercase Letters</b> ?</li>
                    <li>Would you like <b>Special Characters</b> ?</li>
                </ol>
                <h5>You must select at least 1 set of Characters.</h5>  

            </section>

            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="card-footer">
                    <button id="generate" class="btn">Generate Password</button>
            </div>

        </main>

    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript link -->
    <script src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/v2.0.6/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ko_passGen_scriptCopy.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

and here is the JavaScript

```
// declare and initialize the arrays
var numBersArr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

var uppCaseArr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
  'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
];
var lowCaseArr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
  't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
];
var specCharArr = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '*', '@', '[', '^', '{', '}', '~'];

function generatePassword() {
  // declare the object. it will be populated by a push from if statements below where
  var pwData = {
    comboArray: [],
  };

  // verify that the password length is correct -------------------
  while (userInputPwLength < 8 || userInputPwLength > 128 || isNaN(userInputPwLength)) {
    if (userInputPwLength < 8) {
      alert("Sorry the Password Length is too Short.")
    };
    if (userInputPwLength > 128) {
      alert("Sorry the Password is too Long.")
    };
    var userInputPwLength = parseInt(prompt("Pick a password length of 8 to 128 characters"));
  };

  // prompt for which character sets are used
  // and validate that at least one character set is actaully selected
  var userInputNumb = false, userInputUpper = false, userInputLower = false, userInputSpec = false;

  while ((userInputNumb === false) && (userInputUpper === false) && (userInputLower === false) && (
      userInputSpec === false)) {
    alert("Please pick at least 1 of these sets: \n  Numbers \n  Upper Case Letters \n  Lower Case Letters \n  Special Characters");
    userInputNumb = confirm('Want "Numbers" in your passwword?');
    userInputUpper = confirm('Want "UPPERCASE LETTERS" in your password ?');
    userInputLower = confirm('Want "lower case letters" in your password ?');
    userInputSpec = confirm('Want "Special characters" in your password ?');
  };

  // push a new key.value pair of combined character sets to pwData.comboArray -------------
  if (userInputNumb == true) {
    pwData.comboArray.push(numBersArr);
  };

  if (userInputUpper == true) {
    pwData.comboArray.push(uppCaseArr);
  };

  if (userInputLower == true) {
    pwData.comboArray.push(lowCaseArr);
  };

  if (userInputSpec == true) {
    pwData.comboArray.push(specCharArr);
  };

  // begin loop to concatenate string__
  let x = 0;

  var passwordString = "";

  while (x < userInputPwLength) {
    // 1st Math.Random returns a random number from the number of Character sets requested by user
    // which is found by looking at how many arrays are pushed(nested) to comboArray
    var indexA = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pwData.comboArray.length));
    // 2nd Math.Random returns a random number index of the nested array found from the first random number
    var indexB = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pwData.comboArray[indexA].length - 1));
    var passwordString = passwordString + pwData.comboArray[indexA][indexB];
    x++
  };
  return passwordString;
};

// ____________Provided code below__________________________

// Assignment Code
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.value = password;
  scrollToTop();
}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);

function scrollToTop() {
  window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
  // copyToPasteboard();
};

//   -  errors out in real time
function copyToPasteboard() {
  var askIfCopy = confirm('Want to copy your password to the clipboard?');
  if (askIfCopy) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(password.value)
      .then(function () {
        alert("Text copied to clipboard successfully");
      })
      .catch(function () {
        alert("An error occurred copying the text to the clipboard.");
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, can you try to console value just before `navigator.clipboard.writeText(password.value)` line. Can you see `password.value` properly?

Comment: Yes, it is seen.  But this morning repeating the problem is troublesome.  It seems to be intermittent and I can not reproduce, success or failure with any certainty. I am not sure what is triggering the issue at this point.

Comment: I did see an error earlier in the console "Document not focused" so I realized that at times I am able to get the copy to work only if 1. I still have breaks in the script, and 2., if I select continue only in the browser window, not if I continue in the DevTools Sources script runner window. It doesn't work if I remove the breaks at all though.

Comment: *document not focused* error will come whenever your browser is trying to run copy command but the original document is not focused. second clipboard.writeText() is asynchronous function which returns a promise.